# Gather nameof and object at the same time

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to put together a class which will gather a **Dictionary**. Then later print those objects to the console. Mostly so that you can see the end runtime values of numerous test cases without debugging each one and also to avoid a lot of manual Console.WriteLines.

[This works when I do this but its not quite right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USyr4.png)

```
    private Dictionary<string, object> Localvars = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void InsertEntry(string objectName, object objectToAdd, string description)
    {
        Localvars.Add(objectName + $": {description}", objectToAdd);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = new Demo();
        var charizard = "Fire type that looks like a dragon";
        var blastoise = "Water type that resembles a turtle with cannon barrels sticking out of its shell";
        var pikachu = "Electric type that resembles a cute electric rodent";
        d.InsertEntry(nameof(charizard), charizard, "The first one");
        d.InsertEntry(nameof(blastoise), blastoise, "The second one");
        d.InsertEntry(nameof(pikachu), pikachu, "The third one");
        d.PrintVars();
    }
```

[This is closer to how I'd prefer to do it but it throws an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRjqG.png)

```
    private Dictionary<string, object> Localvars = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public void InsertEntry(object objectToAdd, string description = "")
    {
        Localvars.Add(nameof(objectToAdd) + $": {description}", objectToAdd);
    }        

    public void InsertEntry(params object[] objectToAdd)
    {
        Localvars.Add(nameof(objectToAdd), objectToAdd);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = new Demo();
        var charizard = "Fire type that looks like a dragon";
        var blastoise = "Water type that resembles a turtle with cannon barrels sticking out of its shell";
        var pikachu = "Electric type that resembles a cute electric rodent";
        // This is ideally how I'd like it to work
        d.InsertEntry(charizard);
        d.InsertEntry(blastoise);
        d.InsertEntry(pikachu);
        // Or this would be even better if the method could take params. I imagine it would be the same solution.
        d.InsertEntry(charizard, pikachu, blastoise);
        d.PrintVars();
    }
```

Now I know *why* it's throwing the error in question. It complains that *"An item with the same key has already been added"* because when I attempt to get the **nameof** the variable its being passed in as the argument *objectToAdd*. Which means the Key in the dictionary is being set to *objectToAdd* instead of *charizard, blastoise,* or *pikachu*.

Obviously I can pass it in as a string using **nameof** and this is vastly more readable than the memory expressions I've seen elsewhere. Is there some way I can pass the object in as a parameter to another method so that I can get **both** the **name** *and* the **content** if the member? I've reviewed various ideas such as the ref and out keywords but they don't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Is there some way I can pass the object in as a parameter to another method so that I can get both the name and the content of the member?"

```
var charizard = "fire type...";
Foo(() => charizard);

private void Foo<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
{
    var memberName = GetMemberName(memberExpression); // "charizard"
    var expressionValue = memberExpression.Compile().Invoke();  // "fire type..."
}

private string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
{
    var expressionBody = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body;
    return expressionBody.Member.Name;
}
```

Note that this will only work for "member expressions" i.e. () => variables, properties, fields; it will throw otherwise. This is the only way of doing this in C#, as far as I'm aware. Also note it is possible to have `params Expression<Func<T>>[]` as an argument (then `Foo(() => charizard, () => pikachu, ...);`

Comment: I had to alter the second line of the **Foo** method so that it reads `memberExpression.Compile().Invoke();` since `argumentExpression` does not exist within the confines of the method. 

That's *really* quite impressive and I'm very grateful at how fast you answered. Can you please change your answer in accordance with the above that it works in case anyone else comes looking?

Comment: @Imbaker1234 fixed. I've needed to solve the same issue some time ago.. btw, looking at it now, using `dictionary["charizard"]="fire type...";` etc. wouldn't work for you? You would store <name, text> pairs in a dictionary directly, and work with them as such

Comment: Oh that would. There are many things that **WOULD** work here. My goal was to create a clean concise way of tracking objects and printing them to the console during unit testing. It's only a small advantage but software development is a flurry of incremental improvements.

So now if I have 6 variables to track and print I can simply add the objects, of any kind, and it works. A dictionary would work but would be lengthier.

I'm of course aware you can simply debug but when I've created 9 test cases on 20 different methods its nice to be able to view the results at a glance.